# How to call the service within the config in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need to call the service within the configuration .Initially have written a code in configuration

```
    .constant('apiEndpoint', 'www.example.com')//constant is used
```

It's working fine.

Now i need to remove this above code in configuration and added json file.
Below is the json data

```
 {
 "apiEndpoint":"www.example.com"   // json file data
 }
```

I want to read this data in configuration. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not 100% certain that I understand what you're asking. Please could you provide a little more information?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use some tool like `grunt` for generate `json` file `angular config` js.

Or

2. load `json` file, create `config` and then `boostrap` your application. [Angular Boostrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)